# UITableView with dynamic height in UIPopoverController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uipopovercontroller

I have `UITableView` with dynamic cell height and I need to present this `UITableView` in popover, so I need to set the content size for the `UITableView`.

Now is't a hardcode, so in viewDidLoad I have:

```
self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(320, 310);
```

But I need to change the height of the popover according to the height of the table. Is it possible to implement this? Any help?

Answer (score 1):

In `popOverViewConotroller.m`

```
-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    self.preferredContentSize = myTableView.contentSize;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(self.tableView.bounds.size.width, self.tableView.bounds.size.height);
```

Comment: I think, that self.tableView.bounds called before tableView initialization in viewDidLoad. So I have a popover with your method with bounds of the screen.